# Wordpress plugin works like a page creator

Tags: wordpress

I'm building a site for a home builder who wants a page built for each home he has listed. I have no problem doing this by hand, except that he'll be adding new homes himself later. I'm looking for a plugin where I can set up custom fields like address, price, square footage, etc - use CSS to control what the page looks like and where each field goes, and then he can just fill in all the fields and have the page created for him. Does anything like this exist?

I know there are real estate plugins that can do something similar, but I need to be able to control the design myself and insert the short code for the  slideshows that we're already using - the client was so particular about what his slideshow looks like that it took me 4 tries to find one that he was okay with.

Comment: why not create a custom post type, that will let you do all of that without a plugin

Comment: @DavidChase that she's asking this question makes me think that she doesn't want to deal with the php.

Comment: I don't mind dealing with PHP, just don't have a lot of experience with it. I haven't dealt with custom post types before, but I will look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search lead me to this [Custom Post Type Maker](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-maker/).
As you haven't given any specification as to how you intend to incorporate your posts into your theme, I can't tell you if the plugin will work.

I suggest, though, that you may find this [Codex Page about Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) enlightening.

Comment: Thanks, both solutions sound like they would work. I was definitely limited in my search results from not knowing what terms to search for.